# Perl eval('use someModule;') called multiple times. Is it also evaluated multiple times?

Tags: perl, module, eval

I have to deal with a peace of code that uses

```
eval('use someModule');
```

in a function and evals the module during runtime.

Unfortunately the function with this eval block is called multiple times.
Now the question - Is Perl evaluating the module each time the function with this block is called? - Or is Perl smart enough to skip a second eval?
And is there a way to measure that to be sure?

I have tried some global var counting in the BEGIN block of the module, but I'm not sure this is a sufficient test.

Comment: If it's not a variable module name it would be better to write `require someModule;` to load it at runtime and die if it fails to load, then `someModule->import;` if you also need to run its import routine. If it is a variable module name consider [Module::Runtime](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Runtime) which will avoid any potential for string-evaling code you didn't mean to.

Comment: In some parts it's a dynamic module name. But thanks for the hint with Module::Runtime. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

```
use someModule
```

is equivalent to:

```
BEGIN { require someModule; someModule->import(); }
```

and [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) demands that a library file be included if it hasn't already been included.

So someModule will be read and compiled only once, but its `import` sub (if any) will be called once for each `use`.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the quick reqply.